# Why does gcc "--as-needed" flag cause a missing symbol?

Tags: c++, linker

```
g++ [...] -ldiskcache_i [...] -lDCache  [...]
```

links and runs fine, but

```
g++ [...] -Xlinker --as-needed  -ldiskcache_i [...] -lDCache  [...]
```

gives a missing symbol:

```
libdiskcache_i.so: undefined reference to `TDCacheFile::Stage(char const*, unsigned int, char const*)'
```

Both of these libraries are shared objects.

The symbol is requested in `-ldiskcache_i` and should be resolved in
`-lDCache`, as it is before the as-needed flag is introduced.  The only
funny thing about this method is that it is a static method of class `TDCacheFile`,
and the call uses the static property.

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/asneeded.xml).  diskcache_i.so should have been linked against DCache.so when it was created.  If it had been, the dependency would have been detected (can be checked with ldd).  Apparently --as-needed drops libraries from the link if there is no shared object dependence, it does not look into every lib for symbols before deciding what libraries to use.